# Combine Publish, RefCount and Repeat with Rx.NET

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have the following simplified use case:

I have a form. Opening the form tells the user to scan his papers (barcodes). Each scan should be displayed so that the users understands "oh, yes, scanner works".
With each scan I have to query a SAP webservice asking for something e.g. authorization.

So the scanner is my Observable and I have two Observers

- the form displaying the scanned strings
- and a long running process for working with the scan results

I implemented the scanner as a Connectable Obserable by using Publish so that both subscriptions always get the same results. I don't care if the scanner starts immediatly scanning and producing values as long as every scan is pushed in the correct order to each Observer - even to an Observer that connects after some seconds. Here is a **working solution**:

```
    var scanner = new BarcodeScanner();
    var sapBackend = new SapBackend();

    var scans = scanner.ListenToScanner().Publish();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    Print("Starting Subscription 1", ConsoleColor.Red);
    var sub1 = scans.Subscribe(val => NotifyUser(val));
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    Print("Starting Subscription 2", ConsoleColor.Green);
    var sub2 = scans
        .SelectMany(scan => sapBackend.CheckAuthorization(scan))
        .Subscribe(answer => GateInIfAllowed(answer));

    Print("Starting Producer\n", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
    var scannerObservation = scans.Connect();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    sub1.Dispose();
    sub2.Dispose();
    scannerObservation.Dispose();

    Console.ReadKey();
```

[Output of this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lkpm.png)

So what I don't like on this solution is that I don't want to

1. connect explicitly to the Connectable Observable
2. have to store the IDisposable of the connect()
3. have to subscribe with each Observer before the connect()

I would prefer a solution with RefCount, so that the Observable is disposed automatically.
And I'd like to use Repeat(), so that I can subscribe after the scanner have already started to produce some values.
But I wasn't able to compose it that way since Repeat() and RefCount() don't like each other.

**Full Code Sample**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace RxDemo.PlaygroundConsole
{
    internal class Sample4 : IAmASample
    {
        public void TimeToDemonstrate()
        {
            var scanner = new BarcodeScanner();
            var sapBackend = new SapBackend();

            var scans = scanner.ListenToScanner().Publish();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            Print("Starting Subscription 1", ConsoleColor.Red);
            var sub1 = scans.Subscribe(val => NotifyUser(val));
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            Print("Starting Subscription 2", ConsoleColor.Green);
            var sub2 = scans
                .SelectMany(scan => sapBackend.CheckAuthorization(scan))
                .Subscribe(answer => GateInIfAllowed(answer));

            Print("Starting Producer\n", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            var scannerObservation = scans.Connect();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            sub1.Dispose();
            sub2.Dispose();
            scannerObservation.Dispose();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Print(string message, ConsoleColor color)
        {
            var col = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = col;
        }

        private void GateInIfAllowed(string restriction)
        {
            Print(restriction, ConsoleColor.Green);
        }

        private void NotifyUser(string val)
        {
            Print($"UI NOTIFICATION: you scanned {val}", ConsoleColor.Red);
        }

        private class SapBackend
        {
            public IObservable<string> CheckAuthorization(string val)
            {
                //return GetValueSimulatingWebserviceCall(val).ToObservable();
                return Observable
                    .FromAsync(() => GetValueSimulatingWebserviceCall(val));
            }

            private Task<string> GetValueSimulatingWebserviceCall(string val)
            {
                Task.Delay(2000);

                var restriction = "can";
                if (DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0)
                    restriction = "cannot";

                return Observable.Return($"User {restriction} gate in for scan {val}").ToTask();
            }
        }

        private class BarcodeScanner
        {
            private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

            public IObservable<string> ListenToScanner()
            {
                return Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                    .Select(_ => RandomString(6))
                    .Do(val =>
                    {
                        var col = Console.ForegroundColor;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine("Scanner produced " + val);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = col;
                    });
            }

            private static string RandomString(int length)
            {
                const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
                return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
                    .Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`Replay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) operator instead of the `Publish`?

Comment: Thanks very much. That was the missing part.